# Finding all the Enviorment Variables in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, environment-variables, documentation

I recently got a book on shell scripting in bash. It states to list all the Environment Variables using the printenv command. I've noticed though that this doesn't list all variables, for example $PWD or $REPLY or $SSH_TTY. Is their a complete list I can reference for all of these Environment Variables and their Functions?

Comment: `$REPLY` is a builtin variable from the shell not environment. for your question try `declare -x`

Comment: The `set` command might do what you want.

Comment: What is the difference between the an Environment Variable and a shell built-in variable? They are both set by the shell not the user?

Comment: Apropos the initial  question, `set` and `declare -x` seem to be working for me. Thank You

Comment: `printenv` will show all the environment variables *that are set in your current shell*. It doesn't show all that *could be set* (you can technically set almost any string as an environment variable). There are a large number that *will be set* under certain circumstances (e.g. in an ssh session); or that, if set, would have a special function (e.g. the `LANG` and `LC_*` variables, which would tell programs what locale to use; see `man locale`). There are no full lists of those, because anyone who writes a program can make it create/react to any variable they want, thus creating a new one.

Comment: @Xenon : `PATH` certainly will be listed by `printenv`. Try a `printenv PATH` and `printenv|grep ^PATH`. Both should show this variable. If it does not show, the variable is not set.  `REPLY` is not an environment variable, unless you explicitly export it. I don't know whether `SSH_TTY` is placed in the environment, but does this variable exist in your case, i.e. are on an interactive ssh connection?

Answer (score 4):

Within a shell like bash there are two types of variables; [environment variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Environment.html) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable)) and [shell variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html).  There are a number of [predefined shell variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Variables.html).

You can use the [`export`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-export) built-in to "promote" a shell variable to an environment variable, which has the effect of making that variable available to any subprocesses launched from the shell.

As the name implies, [`printenv`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/printenv-invocation.html) only reports the process' environment variables. Variables like `PWD` or `REPLY` are shell variables, and thus aren't displayed. As suggested in the comments, invoking [`set`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) with no arguments will print all variables (environment and shell) available in your current session.

Answer (score 0):

To display a list of the Environment Variables you can use

```sh
set

#if you want to see it nicely you can pipe it to more like this
set | more
```

Comment: `set` will show both shell and environment variables, without distinguishing which are which.

Comment: @OdedBD : The OP explicitly asked for _environment_ variables. Asides from this, `set` is certainly useful, and we should point out that it additionally lists the functions as well.